# Correcting sf great circle ggplots

Tags: r, geo, r-sf

I am attempting to plot several great circles between points on a world map. I am using sf to generate the great circles, largely following the method outlined [here](https://www.jessesadler.com/post/great-circles-sp-sf/). I am able to generate the plot and lines all ok, except several of the lines wrap around behind the globe so to speak, and I end up with a horizontal line connecting the two points where the great circle paths wrap around - see "Correcting gcIntermediate" [here](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/how-to-draw-connecting-routes-on-map-with-r-and-great-circles.html) for a visual explanation and a solution for gcIntermediate.
 Looking at the sf dataframe that has been created, my guess is that I need to split the items where absolute longitude difference is greater than 180 degress into two sf lines. I can kind of see a method that involves many lines of code brute forcing the sf dataframe to resolve this issue, but would very like to see if there are any other better ideas to solve this elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

st_wrap_dateline to the rescue!

```
path.sf <- st_wrap_dateline(path.sf,
                    options=c("WRAPDATELINE=YES", "DATELINEOFFSET=180"))
```

Then plotting this with ggplot2 seems to plot all ok.